# Fork a dex aggregator

Tags: solidity, decentralized-exchange, 1inch-dex-aggregator

I'm trying to build a dex aggregator for myself, but dex aggregators are not open source so they cant be easily forked, actually I don't want to use the sdk, my goal is to build a complete dex aggregator to write the contracts myself and connect the front end to it, I tried the following dex aggregators but cant find their full source: 1inch , paraswap ,hera , matcha , zapper , open ocean

If anyone has experience in this field, please help me

Comment: Start with a regular dex. Dex agregator are tools running off-chain to get other dex operations.

Comment: I need to create a dex aggregator not a normal dex